# Develop programmatically a Jgroup Channel for Infinispan in a Cluster

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, wildfly, infinispan, jgroups

I'm working with infinispan 8.1.0 Final and Wildfly 10 in a cluster set up.

Each server is started running

```
C:\wildfly-10\bin\standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-ha.xml -b 10.09.139.215 -u 230.0.0.4  -Djboss.node.name=MyNode
```

I want to use Infinispan in distributed mode in order to have a distributed cache. But for mandatory requirements I need to build a JGroups channel for dynamically reading some properties from a file.

This channel is necessary for me to build a cluster-group based on TYPE and NAME (for example Type1-MyCluster). Each server who wants to join a cluster has to use the related channel.

Sailing the net I have found some code like the one below:

```
public class JGroupsChannelServiceActivator implements ServiceActivator  { 
    @Override 
public void activate(ServiceActivatorContext context) { 
    stackName = "udp"; 
    try { 
        channelServiceName = ChannelService.getServiceName(CHANNEL_NAME); 
        createChannel(context.getServiceTarget()); 
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
        log.log(Level.INFO, "channel seems to already exist, skipping creation and binding."); 
    } 
}
void createChannel(ServiceTarget target) { 

    InjectedValue<ChannelFactory> channelFactory = new InjectedValue<>(); 
    ServiceName serviceName = ChannelFactoryService.getServiceName(stackName); 
    ChannelService channelService = new ChannelService(CHANNEL_NAME, channelFactory); 

    target.addService(channelServiceName, channelService) 
    .addDependency(serviceName, ChannelFactory.class, channelFactory).install(); 
}
```

I have created the META-INF/services/....JGroupsChannelServiceActivator file.

When I deploy my war into the server, the operation fails with this error:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [\"jboss.jgroups.channel.clusterWatchdog is missing [jboss.jgroups.stack.udp]\"]}"
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I build a channel the way I need?
In what way I can tell to infinispan to use that channel for distributed caching?

Answer (score 1):

The proposal you found is implementation dependent and might cause a lot of problems during the upgrade. I wouldn't recommend it.

Let me check if I understand your problem correctly - you need to be able to create a JGroups channel manually because you use some custom properties for it.

If that is the case - you could obtain a JGroups channel as suggested [here](https://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_hijack_a_jgroups_channel_inside_infinispan_jboss_and_get_away_with_it). But then you obtain a `JChannel` instance which is already connected (so this might be too late for your case).

Unfortunately since Wildfly manages the `JChannel` (it is required for  clustering sessions, EJB etc) the only way to get full control of `JChannel` creating process is using Infinispan embedded (library) mode. This would require adding `infinispan-embedded` into your WAR dependencies. After that you can initialize it similarly [to this test](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/edb93740b6f4491aaf5f173e2f6d24733c6e8197/core/src/test/java/org/infinispan/remoting/jgroups/ChannelLookupTest.java#L48).